# Add teardown block for single test in Android

Tags: android, testing, io, teardown

In iOS there exists a tear block you can add to individual tests called `addTearDownBlock` and you put it inside a single test and it will only execute for that single test.

Does android have a similar version of this?

Answer (score 0):

Unit testing in android is done with xUnit variation known as JUnit. If you are using JUnit 4.0, then use the following annotation:

```
@AfterClass //Will only execute once after all the tests in the class have exhausted

@After //Will run after every test
```

If you are using JUnit 5.0 then use the following annotation:

```
@AfterEach //Will run after every test

@AfterAll //Will only execute once after all the tests in the class have exhausted
```

Comment: But does there exist one for a single function in a class? I would like one so that I can run a tear down on this one function in the case it fails but I still need to tear something down. Right now if it fails it stops executing and there are tear down steps I would like to execute for only this test